# IHaveBadges - A script to link your badges in the toolbar to your list of badges in your profile

Tags: script, badges

This is a very simple script that, in response to [this Meta Stack Overflow feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/153626/155826), transforms the list of badges in the toolbar to a link to the user's badges in his or her profile.

### Screenshot

[image: badge link separate from summary link]

### About

I wasn't entirely sure there was really a problem to be solved. After all, the list of badges is merely 2 clicks away. However, after installing the script, I find that I use it quite a bit when I want to check out my list of badges.

#### License

This is licensed under the [BSD License](http://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-2-Clause).

#### Download

This can be downloaded from [the IHaveBadges GitHub repository](https://github.com/jamesmortensen/IHaveBadges). Just see the README file for the direct link, or you can [get it directly from here](https://github.com/jamesmortensen/IHaveBadges/raw/master/ihavebadges.user.js).

#### Platform

This is a Userscript, so it works and has been tested with Chrome. I've also tested it with Greasemonkey installed in Firefox, Seamonkey, Midori, and Epiphany. It should work with any open source browser that supports Userscripts.

### Contact

Since I don't suspect this will get a lot of activity, just contact me here.

### Code

Userscripts are written in JavaScript, and the code is in a [public space in Assembla](https://www.assembla.com/code/stackscripts/git/nodes/master/ihavebadges.user.js). Anyone should be able to clone the repo or download the code.

**How can we contribute to the code?**

Let me know if you have anything to contribute and I can merge the changes. It's a public space, so it might be possible to just open it up to any committers.

[image: Thumbnail]

### History

- 1.0: Initial release to the public
- 1.1: Forgot to include stackoverflow.com, of all sites to forget. Also, I commented the console log statement to reduce noise and clutter.
- 1.3: Updated script so that it works with the new top navigation bar as of February, 2014.

Comment: You should make it so that we can just have one link to click, instead of having to download and save the file from an external source

Comment: Good point, @CodyGuldner, Assembla is a poor choice for this. I'm considering moving all this stuff to GitHub because (a) it's easier, and (b) more devs are familiar with GitHub than Assembla.

Comment: Doesn't work with the latest changes to the SE toolbar, correct?

Comment: @slm - Yeh, it doesn't work w/the changes. But, I'm not quite sure how to approach this. In the old toolbar, the badges weren't links. In this one, they link to the profile summary by default. How would you suggest approaching this? Maybe a "badges" link next to the flair?

Comment: @jmort253 - yeah links next to them might not be bad, I was looking at this b/c with the access to my  rep buried in multiple links now, I was wondering if this provided access to the badges + rep.

Comment: @slm - I updated the script so that it works with the new top bar. I just split the badges from the avatar and reputation and linked to the badges. Hope this helps!